# I am having an issue creating a JSONObject on my server(tomcat)

Tags: java, json, ajax, servlets, server

I am calling `doPost` with an ajax call. I am  getting a:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONObject

exception. This only happens when this code is ran on the server(Apache Tomcat), I created a test (MAIN) and ran application as a java application and this works fine.  At the moment I'm only trying to print the contents of a `JSONObject`. I've been at this for over 2 days. I have enclosed a complete [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCw5e.png).[updated error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erlhT.png)

Comment: try to add  jar `java-json.jar` and download it from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm

Comment: add `java-json.jar` add the file to classpath of server. The error simply means that the file not present in your server.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I've done as instructed. Now my server will not start: JSONException class cannot be found...  I have added another screenshot. Note when removing the throws JSONException declaration the server starts fine.